# Python MySQLdb unique records, ignore errors

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm trying to insert records to my db from an array :

```
 for string in self.FinalMailsArray:
            c.execute("""INSERT INTO table (email) VALUES(%s) """,(string))
```

The problem is, that I want the field email to be unique, so I enabled that in the DB. When I start inserting, I get errors for duplicate entry value.

Is there a way where I can say, "if there is a duplicate error thrown, just go to the next string in the array" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[INSERT IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) will ignore inserts that would otherwise conflict with a unique key:

```
for string in self.FinalMailsArray:
    c.execute("""INSERT IGNORE INTO table (email) VALUES(%s) """,(string))
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [try/except](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).